# when do I write my own exception class?

Tags: php, oop, exception

I have been wondering since I stepped into the murky waters of OOP and have written a couple or so of distributed libraries when it is necessary to write my own extension of the exception class.

So far I simply use the built in exception class and it seems to serve me well. Is it necessary, and if so when is it ok, for me to write an exception subclass.

Comment: Are you doing any exception handling (e.g. retry an action), or do you use exceptions mostly for error notification/reporting?

Comment: @Mario they are libraries so I allow 3 error options, throw_error, exceptions and silent. How the user handles them is their concern. However, mostly these are error reporting. Critical errors like file is invalid and syntax error.

Comment: Then I tend to agree that a single exception class is sufficient. In PHP anyway, since it's not so much a core language feature. Diverse exception classes are suitable if they implement recovery or use a pattern that aids the application flow. Development errors don't need that much complexity, I would even go so far and say one can just use PHPs `trigger_error()` most of the time.

Comment: After reading, I've come to the conclusion that exceptions in general should only be used in "exceptional cases" and that it becomes necessary to extend the base exception class only when you need to override methods or add functionality. Exception::getCode() can do the same thing as multiple catch blocks since in both cases you need to know possible exception codes or exception classes. This however is my opinion.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should extend the Exception class with your own Exception types when you need to differentiate between different types of errors. Throwing an `Exception` just means *something went wrong*. You have no idea *what* went wrong though. Should you abort everything? Is this an expected error? Throwing a `UserIsNotAllowedToDoThisException` instead means something much more specific. The importance is to differentiate what code can handle what kind of error:

```
try {
    new Foo($bar);
} catch (UserIsNotAllowedToDoThisException $e) {
    echo "Sorry, you're not allowed to do this.";
}
```

This code handles the simple case when something is not allowed. If `Foo` would throw some other exception, like `TheDatabaseJustCrashedAndIsBurningException`, you don't want to know about this here, you want some global error handler to handle it. By differentiating *what* went wrong, it allows you to handle problems appropriately.

---

OK, here a little more complete example:

First, if you use proper OOP, you *need* Exceptions to fail object constructions. Without being able to fail object constructions, you're ignoring a large part of OOP: type safety and therefore data integrity. See for example:

```
class User {

    private $name = null;
    private $db = null;

    public function __construct($name, PDO $db) {
        if (strlen($name) < 3) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Username too short');
        }
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->db->save($this->name);  // very fictional DB call, mind you
    }

}
```

In this example, we see a lot of things:

- My `User` objects *have* to have a name. Failing to pass a `$name` argument to the constructor will make PHP fail the whole program.

  - The username *needs* to be at least 3 characters long. If it is not, the object cannot be constructed (because an Exception is thrown).
- My `User` objects *have* to have a *valid and working* database connection.

  - Failing to pass the `$db` argument will make PHP fail the whole program.
  - **Failing to pass a valid `PDO` instance will make PHP fail the whole program.**

    - I can't pass just *anything* as the second argument, it needs to be a valid PDO object.
    - This means *if the construction of a `PDO` instance succeeded, I have a valid database connection.* I do not need to worry about or check the validity of my database connection henceforth. That's the same reason I'm constructing a `User` object; if the construction succeeds, I have a valid user (valid meaning his name is at least 3 characters long). I do not need to check this again. Ever. I only need to type hint for `User` objects, PHP takes care of the rest.

So, you see the power that OOP + Exceptions gives you. If you have an instance of an object of a certain type, you can be 100% assured that its data is valid. That's a *huge* step up from passing data arrays around in any halfway complex application.

Now, the above `__construct` may fail due to two problems: The username being too short, or *the database is for whatever reason not working*. The `PDO` object is valid, so the connection was working at the time the object was constructed, but maybe it's gone down in the meantime. In that case, the call to `$db->save` will throw its own `PDOException` or a subtype thereof.

```
try {
    $user = new User($_POST['username'], $db);
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

So I'd use the above code to construct a `User` object. I do *not* check beforehand whether the username is at least 3 characters long, because this would violate the DRY principle. Instead, I'll just let the constructor worry about it. If the construction fails with an `InvalidArgumentException`, I know the username was incorrect, so I'll let the user know about that.

What if the database is down though? Then I cannot continue to do *anything* in my current app. In that case I want to halt my application completely, displaying an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error page. Here's *one* way to do it:

```
try {
    $user = new User($_POST['username'], $db);
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    abortEverythingAndShowError500();
}
```

But this is a **bad** way. The database may fail at any time anywhere in the application. I do *not* want to do this check at every point I'm passing a database connection to anything. What I'll do instead is I let the exception *bubble up*. In fact, it has already bubbled up. The exception was not thrown by `new User`, it was thrown in a nested function call to `$db->save`. The Exception has already traveled up at least two layers. So I'll just let it travel up even further, because *I have set up my global error handler to deal with `PDOExceptions`* (it's logging the error and displays a nice error page). I *do not* want to worry about this particular error here. So, here it comes:

**Using different types of Exceptions allows me to ignore certain types of errors at certain points in my code and let other parts of my code handle them.** If I have an object of a certain type, I do not ever have to question or check or worry about its validity. If it wasn't valid, I wouldn't have an instance of it in the first place. And, if it ever *fails* to be valid (like a suddenly failing database connection), **the object can signal by itself that an error occurred**. All I need to do is `catch` the Exception at the right point (which can be very high up), I do *not* need to check whether something succeeded or not at every single point in my program. The upshot is *less, more robust, better structured code*. In this very simple example, I'm only using a generic `InvalidArgumentException`. In somewhat more complex code with objects that accept many arguments, you'd probably want to differentiate between different types of invalid arguments. Hence you'd make your own Exception subclasses.

Try to replicate this by using only *one* type of Exception. Try to replicate this using only function calls and `return false`. You need *a lot more code* to do so *every time* you need to make that check. Writing custom exceptions and custom objects is a little more code and apparent complexity upfront, but it saves you a ton of code later and makes things *much* simpler in the long run. Because anything that *shouldn't be* (like a user with a too short username) is guaranteed to cause an error of some sort. You don't need to check every time. On the contrary, you only need to worry about at which layer you want to *contain* the error, not whether you'll find it at all.

And it's really no effort to "write your own Exceptions":

```
class UserStoppedLovingUsException extends Exception { }
```

There, you have created your own Exception subclass. You can now `throw` and `catch` it at the appropriate points in your code. You don't need to do any more than that. In fact, you have now a formal declaration of the types of things that may go wrong in your app. Doesn't that beat a lot of informal documentation and `if`s and `else`s and `return false`s?

Comment: `catch (Exception $e) { switch $e->getCode(): ...`

Comment: @OZ_: -1: Decision by Exception is not the same as decision in the standard program flow.

Comment: @hakre: -1000. Exceptions should not be part of the 'standard program flow', it's **Exceptions**.

Comment: @OZ_: Well that's exactly what I've written. You make the exception part of the standard program flow by using the switch statement onto them instead of try/catch.

Comment: @OZ_ So you'd rather switch manually at every point you have an exception instead of letting PHP handle it automatically through type hinting? Seems... clunky, to say the least.

Comment: @OZ_: Not to speak about the problems that switch would make the need of bubbling, to rethrow the non-handeled exception again.

Comment: @hakre lol, I just replace 'declaring 10 exceptions classes' to 'parse 10 codes of exceptions, logic still the same.

Comment: @deceze so you'd rather declare new class for each exception and write new 'catch' for each exception? Seems twice clunky.

Comment: @OZ_ You only need to declare your exception classes **once**, but you have to write your switch code **in every `catch`**. Usually you just want to catch a limited number of handleable exceptions "locally" and want the rest to bubble up. With proper exception classes this works very seamlessly with a minimum of code. Which seems more efficient now?

Comment: @deceze but you need to write catch for **every** declared exception, when I just can write one.

Comment: @OZ_: Your switch variant is making code less fluent, more hardly couples error handling with concrete implementations and you need to code much, much more if your application grows. Keep in mind what you wrote yourself: "Exceptions should not be part of the 'standard program flow', it's Exceptions". That's a very valid point.

Comment: @OZ_ No, you don't have to catch every exception every time. That's the point. In my code above, I would explicitly *not* catch `TheDatabaseJustCrashedAndIsBurningException` exceptions, because I can't do anything about them at that point anyway. I'd let my global error handler worry about it. Also consider that you can have Exception hierarchies. You can catch a whole group of exceptions together without worrying about the particular type of exception.

Comment: @deceze `Usually you just want to catch a limited number of handleable exceptions "locally"` - I hate code where throwing exceptions is the part of standard algorithm. Exception should thrown only when algorithm can not be executed anymore. That's why it's called `Exceptions`.

Comment: @OZ_ `I hate code where throwing exceptions is the part of standard algorithm.` I have never proposed any such thing.

Comment: @OZ_: It looks to me you're speaking about non-complex systems that could just return false if a routine fails as well and it shouldn't introduce any problem to you then. You can set a global error value you switch over then ;) - Exceptions are better in that case for you because functions can still return false if they need it in non-error conditions. And you spare the global as you use the errorCode member of the exception class. But that's only a very limited use of what exceptions offer.

Comment: @hakre you use 'globals' and still thinking that your system is too complex for somebody to understand? yes, spaghetti-code with `globals` is too complex system :)

Comment: @OZ_: Nice you got the analogy. But I was speaking about your suggestion and it's deficiencies. Just in case it got unnoticed to you :) - I mean there is no rule that you can't do it with a switch to handle exception handling, it's just burdersome if the system you deal with is more complex. Systems tend to become more complex the more they grow - whatever design you have. The same it's one reason to not use globals to reduce drawbacks, the same reason to use exceptions instead of error values. And the same reason to use concrete exceptions instead of an overall exception class.

Comment: I'm beginning to feel exceptions are generally a bad idea. I've read somewhere that php coders have a java mindset and also that we catch exceptions too early. It will also seem exception handling is an art. So what happens when I have two possible exceptions in a try block, do I catch(exception $e) or (exceptionOne $e) or (exceptionTwo $e) to cover both, since now maybe in my library the parser can throw and the lexer can throw?

Comment: @hakre if you can't build big system without dozens of Exceptions, it doesn't mean that it's impossible.

Comment: @frotymarvelous: I would not call Exceptions a general bad idea. From my own practice I can say they help to better write and maintain code first of all. And it's much better in the long run even. For your lexer/parser exceptions example: It depends on what you want / need to catch. LexerException and ParserException in PHP are both inherited from Exception, so you can catch both if you want to by catching Exception.

Comment: @OZ_: There is no need in PHP to make use of exceptions. It's completely optional. In older versions it was not even possible to use them.

Comment: @frosty You should catch exception where they are appropriate. For application-halting exceptions like *database-down* errors, let you global error handler worry about it, don't `catch` them anywhere else. To catch different kinds of exceptions and deal with them differently, you can have several `catch` blocks: `try { } catch (Foo $e) { } catch (Bar $e) { }`. You don't usually want to overdo this though and let exceptions bubble instead.

Comment: @deceze so when do u need to diffentiate? I think @oz_ idea of when you need to override is more straightforward.

Comment: @frosty For very shallow calls, sure. But say you call a method which may fail with an exception of its own, say `foo()` may throw an `InvalidValueException`. `foo()` itself is calling `bar()` though. `bar()` is making a call to a database. If the database is down, your database class throws a `DatabaseIsDownException`. So, implicitly `foo()` may throw an `InvalidValueException` or indirectly a `DatabaseIsDownException`. The more complex your application gets, the better you want to differentiate between exceptions and let certain exceptions bubble higher than others!

Comment: @deceze. Honestly, all this is making my head spin. I feel the classic return false on error and use a getError() or equivalent is easier than this complex ,nested, bubbling. Maybe php was not for exceptions after all. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @frosty Simple error reporting mechanisms for simple applications. You don't always need custom exceptions, but for complex projects they can really help. It has nothing to do with PHP, it's pretty much the same thing in all exceptional (pun intended) languages. Maybe you can't appreciate it now. You will once you have run into the limitations of a simple `return false`.

Comment: @deceze: You are right and I think all that "_using `return false` is better_" opinions are just result of not having experienced projects that really needed exceptions with proper hierarchy.

Comment: @frosty I have extended my example, please have another look. If that doesn't convince you… tough luck. :)

Comment: @deceze, first of all I thank you for the time and energy spent on this. Its really good. In your examples, yes the exceptions were thrown in exceptional cases and though that is not the focus of this question, that is my point. The abuse of exceptions. Also, I do understand the benefit of exceptions and do use them especially pdo exceptions. However, I believe large number of custom exceptions can begin to harm code and force devs to know a huge number of possible exceptions. Though not the focus of this question, that is my point; the abuse of exceptions.

Comment: Most times the inbuilt or even false is the way to go. Unless you are building a completely OOP php app with a java mindset. Naturally, I go procedural with oop libraries so I prefer false. Thanks again bro. Really good answer.

Comment: @frosty I see. I didn't see your question as coming from the minimizing POV, but rather from the *"what's the use"* POV. Sure, having a custom exception for *everything* is often overkill. If you have hugely complex systems with nested calls in nested calls though, it can be very beneficial to be able to distinguish which layer threw what exception. As a rule of thumb I'd say the more important and influential an object, the more distinct its exceptions should be, because you'll probably want to catch them father up (see database exceptions vs. simple InvalidArgumentExceptions).

Comment: @frosty If you're properly structuring your exception hierarchy, you can have it both ways though. Let your custom exceptions inherit from standard exceptions like InvalidArgumentException or RuntimeException. You can catch them wholesale in most situations, but have the finer grained control when you need it. You *should* be careful though not to create a forest of exceptions that nobody can follow anymore.

Comment: @deceze a forest huh? I like that :). Ill heed your advice. As I said, exceptions are an art. Knowing how to use them correctly requires skill. Thanks again.ires skill. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Only write it when you need it, e.g. to signal an own exception, for example if you code a library and no exception of the existing ones speaks the same.

See

1. [Core PHP Exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.exceptions.php)
2. [Core PHP SPL Exceptions](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classException.html)

There are a lot of exceptions already build-in in PHP so for the normal program flow things should be covered exception-wise.

If you're developing a more complex system, like a parser, lexer plus compiler and everything is accessed via one routine/faced for it's API, the parser might want to throw a parser exception, the lexer a lexer exception and the compiler a compiler exception.

It can be useful to be able to differentiate. But I normally stick with the build in exceptions, it's easy to refactor later anyway in case it needs more differentiation.

And since there are namespaces nowadays, this is really freaking easy if you stick to the firsthand Exception class from the beginning ;)

Answer (score 2):

The built in exception is good enough for almost every case. The only scenario that I could think of where you **need** another one is when there are more than one exception that can be thrown in a `try` and you want to do different things depending of which one is thrown. You have to distinguish two exceptions. therefore you need another one.

Comment: did you hear about second parameter in constructor of Exception class?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO:
Simply if you enter your own domain.
That is usually indicated when you need additional data to provide in your exception.
So actually you then also have to do you own class to add the additional class members.