# Does it necessary using sef-defined Exception

Tags: php, laravel

As we all konwn,PHP have a class named "Exception"to handle the unexcepting situation.I usually find that someone like self-define a new exception class which extend the class "Exception".  This new exception class do not rewrite or add any function.It just state a children class of the class "Exception".
   so,I doubt that if it is necessary self-define a new Exception class in my project?In the past,I used the class "Exception" in anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when do I write my own exception class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621516/when-do-i-write-my-own-exception-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary, but it might be very convenient: If you have different kinds of exceptions, you can handle them differently when you catch them:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (SpecificException $e) {
    // Do something specific here
} catch (SomeOtherException $e) {
    // Here you can do something else
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // The rest...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to define an exception in that way is to help with debugging and error handling. Not only is something like `NetworkException` more informative, but you can also catch that type of exception when it occurs, so you can deal with different types of exceptions in different ways. Some may be temporary, so you might catch them and ask the user to try again later, for instance.